# Is there a way to revert/cancel a backdrop-filter on a specific area?

Tags: html, css, filter

See this example : https://codepen.io/hl037/pen/dyzvmao

A blur effect is applied on an area of the document, and I would like to have only a specific area without the effect.

Is there a way to cancel the filter in the area under `.blur-off` ?

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
backdrop-filter: blur(0rem);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0rem);
```

to set the value to zero . simple and effective as that

for cancelling the effect on some point in my own media queries.

Comment: This does not work!

Comment: sorry too hear that , couldnt come up with other solution